# URL Encoding leading to invalid flag

Tags: xss, reflected-xss, ctf

I'm currently completing an XSS challenge in a CTF. I successfully redirect the admin cookie to my request bin, but the flag is said to be invalid.

I am told this is because the flag string gets transformed when I try and send it to my own server (e.g. URL encoding messing something up). How would I go about properly encoding the flag to send to my own server?

Comment: Have you tried URL decoding the flag?

Comment: Yes I have tried URL decoding

Comment: Without any further details, the only guess we can give is that you need to perform URL decoding on the cookie value that is received by your server.